# Determining if location is invalid /cached/ (eg underground)

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I’m coding a project in where I need to know the user’s exact position. (LocationManager)

The problem is that for example underground (metro) due to the weak signal the LocationManager can not determine the user’s location, there for it gives back cached location only..

What I do now is that I check whether the location is too old, if so then wait for a new one..

Okay but there’s a problem.. if user doesn’t move at all then location won’t get updated aswell because it will be only a cached location.. the timestamp check will say its too old..

How can I fix that?

Comment: Your question seems circular to me.  Could you re-phrase it?  You're ignoring cached locations (as judged by the location's timestamp), and you're waiting for a non-cached location that you can then trust.  If the user is in a place that can't yield a new location fix, then you're not going to get a new location fix - end of story.  You're choosing to wait for a new location fix, so wait.  What am I missing here?  Maybe also factor in the horizontalAccuracy value in case you do get an occasional fix but it has a huge accuracy value?

Comment: @Smartcat Yeah thats the problem.. If I ignore the old cached locations then the Underground problem gets fixed; but when user is sitting in place then it doesn’t work: I understand why. But then how could I find a way to solve this problem? My app lets users see things nearby, and I need to know somehow if location is okay.. because let’s assume I am at “Station 1” and travel to Station 3: then the app will show things nearby the Station 1 ://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check cache locations by timeStamp you can write in LocationManagerDidUpdateLocation
e.g

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let newLocation = locations.first {
    let age: TimeInterval = -newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
    if age > 120 {
        return
    }
    // ignore old (cached) updates
    if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
        return
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah thank you, this is what I do but the problem is that LocationManager gives back cached (old) location too when user is -for example- sitting in place, not moving. The app will be fooled..

Comment: We have no control over even you can ask location manager for accuracy nearest Ten meters

Comment: locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters